# POST w/ JSON Body - Swift3 - fragments?

Tags: ios, json, post, httprequest, swift3

I'm simply trying to send a JSON string via a Swift3 httprequest.

Tried using a Dictionary, and an escaped string ...

```
func getToken(successHandler: @escaping (Any) -> Void, errorHandler: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://my-api.domain.com/getToken")!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    do
    {
        // try with Dictionary
        let bodyJson: [String: String] = [
            "username": "theusername"
        ]
        let bodyJsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: bodyJson, options: [])

        // try with escaped String
        let jsonString = "{" +
            "\"username\": \"theusername\"," +
        "}"
        let jsonStringData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)


        //request.httpBody = bodyJsonData
        request.httpBody = jsonStringData


        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error)
                errorHandler(error)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Data is empty")
                errorHandler("Data is empty")
                return
            }

            var json: Any? = nil
            do
            {
                json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) {
                    successHandler(json)
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                errorHandler(error)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
    catch
    {
        errorHandler(error)
    }
}
```

I keep getting:

> Handle Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did
>   not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}

I can't find how to try allowing fragments, all of the examples/tutorials are for Swift2.x :/

Unsure what to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// prepare json data
  let mapDict = [ "1":"First", "2":"Second"]

  let json = [ "title":"ABC" , "dict": mapDict ] as [String : Any]

  do {
     let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)

     // create post request
     let endpoint: String = "https://yourAPI"
     let session = URLSession.shared
     let url = NSURL(string: endpoint)!
     let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
     request.httpMethod = "POST"

     // insert json data to the request
     request.httpBody = jsonData


     let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data,response,error in
        if error != nil{
           print(error?.localizedDescription)
           return
        }
     }
     task.resume()
  } catch {
     print("bad things happened")
  }
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm using a Node.JS server (Hapi framework) and am console.log'ing the request.payload and I see what I'm passing, but it weirdly nested so I can't parse it ... request.payload = { ' {"username": "theusername"} ' : ' ' } ... as if my json is nested in single quotes, but is also the key of some next dictionary

Comment: I had to add ... request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") ... all is well, I thank you very much for the help!!! Happy Thanksgiving!!! :)

Comment: does it still happen if you replaced
options: .prettyPrinted
with 
options: []

Comment: Through my debugging one of the first things I did was remove .prettyPrinted for [] ... as I was seeing \n in my request.payload ... so YES is the answer to your question ... I'll test right now with .prettyPrinted ... loading ... both work ... needed the header set though ... I'm not a server/api expert, but is there a way for the server to expect json? Because forgetting to set application/json is a common issue for me :S